# Python Tkinter: Placing items with .place in frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I can't get my head around one thing regarding the .place function for various items on a frame.

The frame is resizing itself to fit the placed items when I use grid or pack, that is known.
However, when I use .place(x, y) to place my items inside the frame, it won't resize itself.

Is there a solution to it? Like update_frame_size(frame.bbox('all')) or something like that?

Here is my code:

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        # Here is the problem:
        for row in range(100):
            tk.Label(self.frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1",
                     relief="solid").place(x=0, y=row*10)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    example = Example(root)
    example.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The trick is not to use .place unless you absolutely have to. If you resize an app using place, then you have to reconfigure their size/position each time. Pack/Grid will do that for you. Given that you are just placing labels 10 pixels apart vertically, why not use grid and change the row number rather than the y coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I use .place(x, y) to place my items inside the frame, it won't resize itself.

That is correct, that is the documented behavior of `place`, and is one of the reasons why `pack` and `grid` are generally the better choice over using `place`.

> Is there a solution to it? Like update_frame_size(frame.bbox('all')) or something like that?

No. If you are using `place`, it is up to you to compute all of the coordinates and sizes yourself.

In your specific example you're stacking labels vertically. For that, `pack` would be a much simpler solution.